# SharePoint 2010 List event handlers cascade

Tags: sharepoint-2010, event-handling, listitem

I have three SharePoint lists as below:

1. GroupCategory
2. GroupName
3. GroupProperties

GroupName has a lookup column to select GroupCategory.
GroupProperties has a lookup column to select GroupName.

Now my scenario is when a GroupName is deleted, I want to delete from GroupProperties all entries for that GroupName. Similarly when a GroupCategory is deleted, I want to delete from GroupName all entries for that GroupCategory.

I know I can write a list ItemDeleted event handler for GroupName and GroupCategory to delete their respective entries from the child list. But my question is: When a GroupCategory item is deleted, and it deletes the child GroupName items, will the ItemDeleted event handlers of GroupName also fire?

Has anyone done this before? Also is there any other way of doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you delete item from list wich has event receiver for ItemDeleted event appropriate code from this receiver will also run regardless of place where event had originally triggered.

So if you have event receiver on list it will be called always when you change item no matter where you doing it from code, UI or powershell.